# Receiving the following error while loading library(tidyverse)

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm receiving the following error while running tidyverse. I have uninstalled and reinstalled rlang, yet the error persists-

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.4.2 is already loaded, but >= 0.5.0 is required
```

Comment: Completely restart R without loading any libraries. `install.packages("vctrs")`. Do again what you tried to do before. R is not always great at _unloading_ packages, so it does not try to unload/update/reload automatically.

Comment: @r2evans - i have doubts regarding R assignment, could you help?

Comment: Did you restart R? We're you able to install `vctrs`?